# MySQL multiple WHERE condition

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get this output with MySQL:
-Kate
-William
-dog
(3 results)

From those databases:

```
---------------    ---------------------- 
|  users      |    |         pet        |
|-------------|    |------|------|-------
| id  | Name  |    |  user|animal|number|
|-------------|    |------|------|------| 
| 1   |Kate   |    |  1   |  cat |   0  |
| 2   |William|    |  2   |  dog |   1  |
---------------    ----------------------
```

Number needs to be != 0
 and I need to be able to make the difference between a fetch where number = 0 and number != 0

```
SELECT
    name, animal  
FROM
    users  
    INNER JOIN pet ON users.id = pet.user 
WHERE
    number != 0'
```

I can't get 'Kate' because never matching != 0.
I think I should use 2 different WHERE conditions in one request, but I don't know how...

Comment: how do you want to filter the names and the pets? also, users and pets are not the same thing... so putting them into a single column is... illogic, maybe?

Comment: It seems you want to use a `UNION`. But I don't understand really why you want this result.

Comment: normally you would have 3 tables, the one your missing joins users to pets (user_id,pet_id)

Comment: The written tables are obviously not the right one. I have 5 linked together, but I tried to make the cause of the problem easy with Kate and Williams. I'll check UNION

Comment: by the way, those are not "databases", but "tables" in a single database

Comment: "obviously not the right one" so we are expected to solve a problem based on wrong data ?

Comment: I want to get the names + the names where number = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First give your tables an alias because you have a ambigious column name `id`.

```
SELECT u.name, p.animal  
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN pet AS p 
ON u.id = p.id  
WHERE p.number != 0
```

But what you asking for is to get results from both tables without join, right? Like this

```
SELECT
    name AS creatur,
    'users' AS type
FROM users  

UNION

SELECT
    animal AS creatur,
    'pet' AS type
FROM pet  
WHERE number != 0
```

Comment: I think this is what I need. Can I do  
`SELECT name FROM users as FirstRequest UNION SELECT animal FROM pet WHERE number != 0 as SecondRequest`

So I'm able to know in php if it comes from 1st or 2nd request?

`if(firstRequest) {} else if(SecondRequest) {}`

Comment: Simply add a constant value as computed column in both queries: `SELECT 'users' as source, name ...` UNION `SELECT 'pet', animal ...`

Comment: As @VMai says, add a second constant column w.l.o.g. `type` that's told you from which table the value is from. And add same alias for first column w.l.o.g. `creatur` to merge the values from `name` and `animal` to one column.

Answer (score 1):

First. Use aliases for tables. Use, for example, 'u' for users table and 'p' for 'pet'. Mysql do not understand which field get from which table without aliases.

Second. Condition in WHERE section not related to JOIN. Use AND in ON section.

Third. Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN and read articles about types of JOIN and differency between them.

Fourth. In such cases in `users` table usually adding field `pet_id`. Do not use single `id` field for both entities. This thing named ONE-TO-MANY relation. If you want use MANY-TO-MANY relation, you must add third table with two fields `user_id` and `pet_id`.

But this query may solve your question:

```
SELECT u.Name, p.animal
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN pet AS p ON u.id = p.user AND p.number != 0
```

Comment: Thank you. The condition is not related to WHERE.
This made it. I still needed to add UNION to get one more data